# calculate prefix maximum of an array

Tags: c

the input of the array is {4, 13, 9, 10, 17, 25, 35, 40, 29, 48, 52, 12, 15, 71, 27, 32}. i need to compare every two elements such as 4 and 13 and the bigger element goes to the temp array and that is compared to next element in the array and so on.

i have this code and it is giving me the array 
{13,10,25,40,48,52,71,32,13,40,52,71,40,71}
    and i need to get output like the following array 
{4, 13, 13, 13, 17, 25, 35, 40, 40, 48, 52, 52, 52, 71, 71, 71}

```
#include <stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
        int pairmax(int[], int);
        int premax(int[], int);
        int  i, j, max1, max2, n;
    n=16;
     int x[16]={4, 13, 9, 10, 17, 25, 35, 40, 29, 48, 52, 12, 15, 71, 27, 32};
        max1 = pairmax(x,n);
        max2 = premax(x, n);

        printf("Pairwise max: Largest = %d\n",max1);
        printf("Prefix max: Largest = %d\n",max2);
    }

    int pairmax(int x[], int n) // Implementation of Pairwise Max
    {
        int max(int, int);
        int y[10], i, j;
        if (n==2)
          return max(x[0], x[1]);
        for(i=0, j=0; i<n;i+=2,j++)
        {
          if(i < n-1)
            y[j] = max(x[i], x[i+1]);
          else
            y[j] = x[i];


    printf("Prefix max: Largest = %d\n",y[j]);
        }
        return pairmax(y,j);
    }


    int premax(int x[], int n) // Implementation of Prefix Max
    {
        int max(int, int);
        int large, i;
        large = x[0];
        for(i=1; i<n;i++)
          large = max(large,x[i]);
        return large;
    }

    int max(int a, int b)
    {
        if (a > b)
          return a;
        else 
          return b;
    }
```

Comment: Alright.  So what is your doubt?

Comment: the current logic is X+Y+1 the code provided follows this logic i need to change it to find maximum number and not the sum the current array takes x = {1, 2, 3,  4,   5,   6,   7,  8 } - Input
y = ( 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36) - Output. and i need like this For example:: x= {4, 13, 9, 10, 17, 25, 35, 40, 29, 48, 52, 12, 15, 71, 27, 32}

The expected output is: y= {4, 13, 13, 13, 17, 25, 35, 40, 40, 48, 52, 52, 52, 71, 71, 71}

Comment: it compares itself to each elements of an array the bigger element goes forward and compares itself to the next element in array. the first element compare itself to 0 to start the process. like 0 and 4 which one is bigger then it will put 4 forward. then in between 4 and 13 which one is bigger then 13 is being forwarded and so on. and i need to print that array.

Comment: `std::powf(2,i)` and `using namespace std;` does not compile in C.  Maybe you want to tag this as a different language?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int array[] = {4, 13, 9, 10, 17, 25, 35, 40, 29, 48, 52, 12, 15, 71, 27, 32};
    int size = sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array);
    int max = array[0];
    int result[size];

    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        if(max < array[i])
            max = array[i];
        result[i] = max;
    }
    //print result
    putchar('{');
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        if(i)
            putchar(',');
        printf("%d", result[i]);
    }
    putchar('}');
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you sooo much BLUEPIXY, can i take input from a file for this array? i have like 10,000 data points and i need to take input from them.

Comment: @samipshah if  simply only to display the sequence without saving it, the same even  if the number of data is large .

Comment: one last question how can i print the largest element in the above program.?

Comment: @samipshah `int max = INT_MIN; while(1==fscanf(in_fp, "%d", &input_value)){ if(max < input_value) max = input_value; printf("%d ", max); } puts("");`